# Get the row index of each extracted character from csv file

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a column (second column called second_column) in my csv file which represents à list of characters and its positions as follow: the column called `character_position`

Each line of this column contains a list of character_position . overall l have 300 lines in this column each with list of `character position`

```
character_position = [['1', 1890, 1904, 486, 505, '8', 1905, 1916, 486, 507, '4', 1919, 1931, 486, 505, '1', 1935, 1947, 486, 505, '7', 1950, 1962, 486, 505, '2', 1965, 1976, 486, 505, '9', 1980, 1992, 486, 507, '6', 1995, 2007, 486, 505, '/', 2010, 2022, 484, 508, '4', 2025, 2037, 486, 505, '8', 2040, 2052, 486, 505, '3', 2057, 2067, 486, 507, '3', 2072, 2082, 486, 505, '0', 2085, 2097, 486, 507, '/', 2100, 2112, 484, 508, 'Q', 2115, 2127, 486, 507, '1', 2132, 2144, 486, 505, '7', 2147, 2157, 486, 505, '9', 2162, 2174, 486, 505, '/', 2175, 2189, 484, 508, 'C', 2190, 2204, 487, 505, '4', 2207, 2219, 486, 505, '1', 2241, 2253, 486, 505, '/', 2255, 2268, 484, 508, '1', 2271, 2285, 486, 507, '5', 2288, 2297, 486, 505], ['D', 2118, 2132, 519, 535, '.', 2138, 2144, 529, 534, '2', 2150, 2162, 516, 535, '0', 2165, 2177, 516, 535, '4', 2180, 2192, 516, 534, '7', 2196, 2208, 516, 534, '0', 2210, 2223, 514, 535, '1', 2226, 2238, 516, 534, '8', 2241, 2253, 514, 534, '2', 2256, 2267, 514, 535, '4', 2270, 2282, 516, 534, '0', 2285, 2298, 514, 535]]
```

each character has for values : left, top, right, bottom. For instance character '1' has left=1890, top=1904, right=486, bottom=505.

My file whole csv file is as follow :

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer='list_characters.csv', header=None, usecols=[1], names=['character_position])
```

From this file l created a new csv file  with five columns :

```
column 1:  character, column 2 : left , column 3 : top, column 4 : right, column 5 : bottom.
cols = ['char','left','top','right','bottom']
df1 = df.character_position.str.strip('[]').str.split(', ', expand=True)
df1.columns = [df1.columns % 5, df1.columns // 5]
df1 = df1.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
df1.columns = cols
df1[cols[1:]] = df1[cols[1:]].astype(int)
print (df1)
   char  left  top  right  bottom
0   'm'    38  104   2456    2492
1   'i'    40  102   2442     222
2   '.'   203  213    191     198
3   '3'   235  262    131    3333
4   'A'   275  347    147     239
5   'M'   363  465    145    3334
6   'A'    73   91    373     394
7   'D'    93  112    373      39
8   'D'   454  473    663     685
9   'O'   474  495    664      33
10  'A'   108  129    727     751
11  'V'   129  150    727     444
```

l want to add 2 other column called `line_number` and `all_chars_in_same_row` 
1)`line_number` corresponds to the line where for example 'm'    38  104   2456    2492 is extracted let say from line 2
2)  `all_chars_in_same_row` corresponds to all (spaced) characters which are in the  same row. for instance

```
character_position = [['1', 1890, 1904, 486, 505, '8', 1905, 1916, 486, 507, '4', 1919, 1931, 486, 505, '1', 1935, 1947, 486, 505, '7', 1950, 1962, 486, 505, '2', 1965, 1976, 486, 505, '9', 1980, 1992, 486, 507, '6', 1995, 2007, 486, 505, '/', 2010, 2022, 484, 508, '4', 2025, 2037, 486, 505, '8', 2040, 2052, 486, 505, '3', 2057, 2067, 486, 507, '3', 2072, 2082, 486, 505, '0', 2085, 2097, 486, 507, '/', 2100, 2112, 484, 508, 'Q', 2115, 2127, 486, 507, '1', 2132, 2144, 486, 505, '7', 2147, 2157, 486, 505, '9', 2162, 2174, 486, 505, '/', 2175, 2189, 484, 508, 'C', 2190, 2204, 487, 505, '4', 2207, 2219, 486, 505, '1', 2241, 2253, 486, 505, '/', 2255, 2268, 484, 508, '1', 2271, 2285, 486, 507, '5', 2288, 2297, 486, 505], ['D', 2118, 2132, 519, 535, '.', 2138, 2144, 529, 534, '2', 2150, 2162, 516, 535, '0', 2165, 2177, 516, 535, '4', 2180, 2192, 516, 534, '7', 2196, 2208, 516, 534, '0', 2210, 2223, 514, 535, '1', 2226, 2238, 516, 534, '8', 2241, 2253, 514, 534, '2', 2256, 2267, 514, 535, '4', 2270, 2282, 516, 534, '0', 2285, 2298, 514, 535]]
```

l get '1' '8' '4' '1' '7' and so on.

more formally :
all_chars_in_same_row means: write all the character of the given row in line_number column

```
char  left  top  right  bottom     line_number  all_chars_in_same_row
0   'm'    38  104   2456    2492   from line 2  'm' '2' '5' 'g'
1   'i'    40  102   2442     222   from line 4
2   '.'   203  213    191     198   from line 6
3   '3'   235  262    131    3333  
4   'A'   275  347    147     239
5   'M'   363  465    145    3334
6   'A'    73   91    373     394
7   'D'    93  112    373      39
8   'D'   454  473    663     685
9   'O'   474  495    664      33
10  'A'   108  129    727     751
11  'V'   129  150    727     444
```

**EDIT1:**

```
import pandas as pd
df_data=pd.read_csv('/home/ahmed/internship/cnn_ocr/list_characters.csv')

df_data.shape
```

(50, 3)

```
df_data.icol(1)   
0     [['m', 38, 104, 2456, 2492, 'i', 40, 102, 2442...
1     [['.', 203, 213, 191, 198, '3', 235, 262, 131,...
2     [['A', 275, 347, 147, 239, 'M', 363, 465, 145,...
3     [['A', 73, 91, 373, 394, 'D', 93, 112, 373, 39...
4     [['D', 454, 473, 663, 685, 'O', 474, 495, 664,...
5     [['A', 108, 129, 727, 751, 'V', 129, 150, 727,...
6     [['N', 34, 51, 949, 970, '/', 52, 61, 948, 970...
7     [['S', 1368, 1401, 43, 85, 'A', 1406, 1446, 43...
8     [['S', 1437, 1457, 112, 138, 'o', 1458, 1476, ...
9     [['h', 1686, 1703, 315, 339, 't', 1706, 1715, ...
10    [['N', 1331, 1349, 370, 391, 'C', 1361, 1379, ...
11    [['N', 1758, 1775, 370, 391, 'D', 1785, 1803, ...
12    [['D', 2166, 2184, 370, 391, 'A', 2186, 2205, ...
13    [['2', 1395, 1415, 427, 454, '0', 1416, 1434, ...
14    [['I', 1533, 1545, 487, 541, 'I', 1548, 1551, ...
15    [['P', 1659, 1677, 490, 514, '2', 1680, 1697, ...
16    [['1', 1890, 1904, 486, 505, '8', 1905, 1916, ...
17    [['B', 1344, 1361, 583, 607, 'O', 1364, 1386, ...
18    [['B', 1548, 1580, 979, 1015, 'T', 1586, 1619,...
19    [['Q', 169, 190, 1291, 1312, 'U', 192, 210, 12...
20    [['1', 296, 305, 1492, 1516, 'S', 339, 357, 14...
21    [['G', 339, 362, 1815, 1840, 'S', 365, 384, 18...
22    [['2', 1440, 1455, 2047, 2073, '9', 1458, 1475...
23    [['R', 339, 360, 2137, 2163, 'e', 363, 378, 21...
24    [['R', 339, 360, 1860, 1885, 'e', 363, 380, 18...
25    [['0', 1266, 1283, 1951, 1977, ',', 1287, 1290...
26    [['1', 2207, 2217, 1492, 1515, '0', 2225, 2240...
27    [['1', 2364, 2382, 1552, 1585], [], ['E', 2369...
28                      [['S', 2369, 2382, 1833, 1866]]
29    [['0', 2243, 2259, 1951, 1977, '0', 2271, 2288...
30    [['0', 2243, 2259, 2227, 2253, '0', 2271, 2286...
31    [['D', 76, 88, 2580, 2596, 'é', 91, 100, 2580,...
32    [['ü', 1474, 1489, 2586, 2616, '3', 1541, 1557...
33    [['E', 1440, 1461, 2670, 2697, 'U', 1466, 1488...
34    [['2', 1685, 1703, 2670, 2697, '.', 1707, 1712...
35    [['1', 2202, 2213, 2668, 2695, '3', 2220, 2237...
36                         [['c', 88, 118, 2872, 2902]]
37    [['N', 127, 144, 2889, 2910, 'D', 156, 175, 28...
38    [['E', 108, 129, 3144, 3172, 'C', 133, 156, 31...
39    [['5', 108, 126, 3204, 3231, '0', 129, 147, 32...
40                                                 [[]]
41    [['1', 480, 492, 3202, 3229, '6', 500, 518, 32...
42    [['P', 217, 234, 3337, 3360, 'A', 235, 255, 33...
43                                                 [[]]
44    [['I', 954, 963, 2892, 2934, 'M', 969, 1011, 2...
45    [['E', 1385, 1407, 2970, 2998, 'U', 1410, 1433...
46    [['T', 2067, 2084, 2889, 2911, 'O', 2088, 2106...
47    [['1', 2201, 2213, 2970, 2997, '6', 2219, 2238...
48    [['M', 1734, 1755, 3246, 3267, 'O', 1758, 1779...
49    [['L', 923, 935, 3411, 3430, 'A', 941, 957, 34...
Name: character_position, dtype: object
```

Then in my  `char.csv` l do the following

```
    df = pd.read_csv('list_characters.csv', header=None, usecols=[1], names=['character_position'])
    df = df.replace(['\[','\]'], ['',''], regex=True)




cols = ['char','left','right','top','bottom']
df1 = df.positionlrtb.str.strip('[]').str.split(',', expand=True)
df1.columns = [df1.columns % 5, df1.columns // 5]
df1 = df1.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
df1.columns = cols
df1.char = df1.char.replace(['\[','\]'], ['',''], regex=True)
df1['left']=df1['left'].replace(['\[','\]'], ['',''], regex=True)
df1['top']=df1['top'].replace(['\[','\]'], ['',''], regex=True)
df1['right']=df1['right'].replace(['\[','\]'], ['',''], regex=True)
df1['bottom']=df1['bottom'].replace(['\[','\]'], ['',''], regex=True)
df1.to_csv('chars.csv')
```

However l don't see in your response how you added the columns `from_line` and `all_char_in_same_rows`.

when l execute your line of code :

```
df_data = df_data.character_position.str.strip('[]').str.split(',', expand=True)
```

l get the following :

```
df_data[0:10]
  0      1      2      3      4     5      6      7      8      9     ...   \
0  'm'     38    104   2456   2492   'i'     40    102   2442   2448  ...    
1  '.'    203    213    191    198   '3'    235    262    131    198  ...    
2  'A'    275    347    147    239   'M'    363    465    145    239  ...    
3  'A'     73     91    373    394   'D'     93    112    373    396  ...    
4  'D'    454    473    663    685   'O'    474    495    664    687  ...    
5  'A'    108    129    727    751   'V'    129    150    727    753  ...    
6  'N'     34     51    949    970   '/'     52     61    948    970  ...    
7  'S'   1368   1401     43     85   'A'   1406   1446     43     85  ...    
8  'S'   1437   1457    112    138   'o'   1458   1476    118    138  ...    
9  'h'   1686   1703    315    339   't'   1706   1715    316    339  ...    
   1821  1822  1823  1824  1825  1826  1827  1828  1829  1830  
0  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  
1  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  
2  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  
3  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  
4  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  
5  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  
6  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  None
```

Here are the 10 first lines of my csv file :

```
    character_position
0   [['m', 38, 104, 2456, 2492, 'i', 40, 102, 2442, 2448, 'i', 40, 100, 2402, 2410, 'l', 40, 102, 2372, 2382, 'm', 40, 102, 2312, 2358, 'u', 40, 102, 2292, 2310, 'i', 40, 104, 2210, 2260, 'l', 40, 104, 2180, 2208, 'i', 40, 104, 2140, 2166, 'l', 40, 104, 2124, 2134]]
1   [['.', 203, 213, 191, 198, '3', 235, 262, 131, 198]]
2   [['A', 275, 347, 147, 239, 'M', 363, 465, 145, 239, 'S', 485, 549, 145, 243, 'U', 569, 631, 145, 241, 'N', 657, 733, 145, 239]]
3   [['A', 73, 91, 373, 394, 'D', 93, 112, 373, 396, 'R', 115, 133, 373, 396, 'E', 136, 153, 373, 396, 'S', 156, 172, 373, 396, 'S', 175, 192, 373, 396, 'E', 195, 211, 373, 396, 'D', 222, 241, 373, 396, 'E', 244, 261, 373, 396, 'L', 272, 285, 375, 396, 'I', 288, 293, 375, 396, 'V', 296, 314, 375, 396, 'R', 317, 334, 373, 396, 'A', 334, 354, 375, 396, 'I', 357, 360, 373, 396, 'S', 365, 381, 373, 396, 'O', 384, 405, 373, 396, 'N', 408, 425, 373, 394]]
4   [['D', 454, 473, 663, 685, 'O', 474, 495, 664, 687, 'C', 498, 516, 664, 687, 'U', 519, 536, 663, 687, 'M', 540, 561, 663, 687, 'E', 564, 581, 663, 685, 'N', 584, 600, 664, 685, 'T', 603, 618, 663, 685]]
5   [['A', 108, 129, 727, 751, 'V', 129, 150, 727, 753, 'O', 153, 175, 727, 753, 'I', 178, 183, 727, 751, 'R', 187, 210, 727, 751, 'S', 220, 240, 727, 753, 'U', 243, 263, 727, 753, 'R', 267, 288, 727, 751, 'F', 302, 318, 727, 751, 'A', 320, 341, 727, 751, 'C', 342, 363, 726, 751, 'T', 366, 384, 726, 750, 'U', 387, 407, 727, 751, 'R', 411, 432, 727, 751, 'E', 435, 453, 726, 751, 'P', 797, 815, 727, 751, 'A', 818, 839, 727, 751, 'G', 840, 863, 727, 751, 'E', 867, 885, 726, 751, '1', 900, 911, 727, 751, '1', 926, 934, 727, 751, '1', 947, 956, 727, 751, '5', 962, 979, 727, 751], ['R', 120, 142, 778, 807, 'T', 144, 165, 778, 805, 'T', 178, 199, 778, 805, 'e', 201, 219, 786, 807, 'c', 222, 240, 786, 807, 'h', 241, 258, 778, 807, 'n', 263, 279, 786, 807, 'i', 284, 287, 778, 805, 'c', 291, 308, 786, 807, 'a', 309, 327, 786, 807, 'R', 350, 374, 778, 807, 'e', 377, 395, 786, 807, 't', 396, 405, 780, 805, 'u', 408, 425, 786, 807, 'r', 429, 440, 786, 807, 'n', 441, 458, 786, 807, '-', 471, 482, 793, 798, 'D', 497, 518, 778, 807, 'O', 522, 548, 777, 807, 'A', 549, 573, 778, 807, '/', 585, 596, 778, 807, 'D', 606, 630, 778, 807, 'A', 632, 656, 778, 807, 'P', 659, 680, 778, 805]]
6   [['N', 34, 51, 949, 970, '/', 52, 61, 948, 970, 'C', 63, 81, 948, 970, 'O', 84, 103, 948, 970, 'M', 106, 127, 949, 970, 'M', 130, 151, 948, 970, 'A', 153, 172, 949, 970, 'N', 175, 192, 949, 970, 'D', 195, 213, 948, 970, 'E', 217, 232, 948, 970], ['1', 73, 84, 993, 1020, '1', 94, 105, 993, 1020, '8', 112, 130, 991, 1020, '4', 135, 153, 993, 1018, '5', 156, 172, 994, 1018, '7', 175, 192, 993, 1018, '6', 195, 213, 993, 1020, '0', 216, 235, 991, 1020, '6', 238, 257, 993, 1020, '5', 260, 278, 993, 1020, '0', 407, 425, 991, 1020, '9', 428, 446, 991, 1020, '.', 450, 455, 1015, 1020, '0', 459, 477, 991, 1020, '1', 485, 494, 994, 1018, '.', 503, 507, 1015, 1020, '2', 512, 530, 991, 1020, '0', 533, 551, 991, 1020, '1', 555, 566, 993, 1020, '5', 575, 593, 993, 1020, 'R', 632, 656, 991, 1020, 'M', 659, 684, 991, 1020, 'A', 689, 713, 991, 1020, 'N', 726, 747, 993, 1020, 'o', 752, 770, 999, 1020, '.', 774, 779, 1015, 1020, '5', 794, 812, 993, 1020, '8', 815, 833, 991, 1020, '4', 834, 852, 993, 1017, '4', 857, 873, 994, 1018, '3', 878, 896, 991, 1020, '8', 899, 917, 991, 1020, '0', 920, 938, 991, 1020, '/', 950, 960, 991, 1020, '0', 971, 990, 993, 1020, '7', 995, 1011, 993, 1018, '1', 1016, 1026, 993, 1018, '6', 1034, 1052, 993, 1020, '7', 1055, 1073, 993, 1020, '4', 1076, 1094, 993, 1018, '8', 1098, 1116, 991, 1020, '9', 1119, 1137, 991, 1020, '0', 1140, 1158, 993, 1020, '9', 1160, 1178, 991, 1020], ['N', 34, 51, 1045, 1066, '/', 54, 61, 1045, 1066, 'B', 63, 79, 1044, 1066, 'O', 82, 102, 1044, 1066, 'N', 105, 121, 1045, 1066, 'D', 133, 151, 1045, 1066, 'E', 156, 172, 1044, 1066, 'L', 183, 196, 1045, 1066, 'I', 199, 204, 1045, 1066, 'V', 205, 223, 1045, 1066, 'R', 226, 244, 1045, 1066, 'A', 246, 266, 1045, 1066, 'I', 267, 272, 1045, 1066, 'S', 275, 291, 1044, 1066, 'O', 294, 314, 1045, 1066, 'N', 318, 335, 1045, 1066], ['8', 72, 90, 1093, 1122, '2', 93, 109, 1093, 1122, '5', 114, 132, 1095, 1122, '9', 135, 153, 1093, 1122, '7', 154, 172, 1095, 1122, '1', 178, 189, 1093, 1122, '3', 196, 214, 1093, 1122, '1', 220, 231, 1095, 1122, '0', 238, 257, 1093, 1122, '3', 260, 278, 1093, 1122, '0', 407, 425, 1093, 1122, '6', 429, 447, 1095, 1122, '.', 452, 455, 1117, 1122, '0', 459, 477, 1093, 1122, '2', 480, 498, 1093, 1122, '.', 503, 507, 1117, 1122, '2', 512, 530, 1093, 1122, '0', 533, 551, 1093, 1122, '1', 557, 567, 1095, 1122, '5', 575, 593, 1095, 1122], ['v', 70, 90, 1150, 1171, '/', 88, 97, 1150, 1171, 'r', 100, 118, 1150, 1171, 'Ã©', 121, 136, 1144, 1173, 'f', 141, 156, 1150, 1171, 'Ãª', 159, 174, 1144, 1173, 'r', 177, 195, 1150, 1173, 'e', 198, 214, 1150, 1171, 'n', 217, 234, 1150, 1171, 'c', 238, 257, 1149, 1171, 'e', 260, 276, 1149, 1173, 'B', 476, 497, 1152, 1179, 'O', 501, 527, 1149, 1179, 'G', 530, 555, 1150, 1180, 'D', 560, 582, 1152, 1179, 'O', 585, 611, 1149, 1179, 'A', 614, 638, 1150, 1179, '1', 642, 653, 1152, 1179, '5', 659, 677, 1153, 1180, 'B', 681, 701, 1152, 1179, 'T', 705, 726, 1152, 1179, '0', 728, 746, 1152, 1179, '6', 749, 767, 1152, 1179]]
7   [['S', 1368, 1401, 43, 85, 'A', 1406, 1446, 43, 85, 'M', 1451, 1491, 36, 85, 'S', 1500, 1533, 43, 85, 'U', 1539, 1574, 43, 85, 'N', 1581, 1616, 43, 85, 'G', 1623, 1662, 42, 85, 'E', 1686, 1719, 43, 85, 'L', 1725, 1755, 43, 85, 'E', 1763, 1794, 42, 85, 'C', 1800, 1836, 43, 85, 'T', 1841, 1874, 42, 85, 'R', 1880, 1914, 42, 84, 'O', 1919, 1959, 42, 85, 'N', 1965, 1998, 42, 84, 'I', 2007, 2016, 42, 84, 'C', 2022, 2058, 42, 84, 'S', 2066, 2099, 42, 84, 'F', 2121, 2151, 42, 84, 'R', 2159, 2193, 42, 84, 'A', 2198, 2237, 40, 84, 'N', 2243, 2277, 40, 84, 'C', 2285, 2321, 42, 84, 'E', 2328, 2360, 40, 84]]
8   [['S', 1437, 1457, 112, 138, 'o', 1458, 1476, 118, 138, 'c', 1479, 1493, 120, 138, 'i', 1494, 1499, 112, 136, 'Ã©', 1503, 1518, 114, 138, 't', 1520, 1527, 115, 138, 'Ã©', 1530, 1547, 112, 138, 'p', 1559, 1575, 120, 144, 'a', 1577, 1593, 118, 138, 'r', 1596, 1607, 118, 136, 'A', 1616, 1637, 112, 136, 'c', 1640, 1653, 118, 138, 't', 1655, 1664, 115, 136, 'i', 1665, 1670, 112, 136, 'o', 1673, 1688, 118, 138, 'n', 1692, 1707, 118, 136, 's', 1710, 1725, 118, 138, 'S', 1736, 1755, 112, 138, 'i', 1760, 1763, 112, 136, 'm', 1767, 1791, 118, 136, 'p', 1794, 1811, 118, 142, 'l', 1812, 1817, 112, 136, 'i', 1821, 1824, 112, 136, 'f', 1827, 1835, 112, 136, 'i', 1835, 1841, 112, 136, 'Ã©', 1845, 1860, 112, 136, 'e', 1863, 1878, 118, 136, 'a', 1890, 1907, 118, 138, 'u', 1910, 1925, 118, 136, 'C', 1937, 1958, 112, 136, 'a', 1961, 1977, 118, 136, 'p', 1980, 1995, 118, 142, 'i', 1998, 2003, 112, 136, 't', 2006, 2013, 114, 136, 'a', 2015, 2030, 118, 136, 'l', 2034, 2037, 112, 136, 'd', 2051, 2066, 111, 136, 'e', 2069, 2085, 117, 136, '2', 2097, 2112, 112, 136, '7', 2115, 2132, 111, 136, '.', 2136, 2139, 132, 136, '0', 2144, 2159, 111, 136, '0', 2162, 2178, 111, 136, '0', 2180, 2196, 111, 136, '.', 2201, 2205, 132, 135, '0', 2208, 2225, 111, 136, '0', 2228, 2243, 111, 136, '0', 2246, 2261, 111, 136, 't', 2273, 2281, 112, 135, 'i', 2281, 2291, 111, 136], ['1', 1473, 1482, 153, 177, ',', 1491, 1494, 172, 181, 'r', 1508, 1517, 159, 177, 'u', 1520, 1535, 160, 177, 'e', 1538, 1554, 159, 177, 'F', 1566, 1583, 153, 177, 'r', 1587, 1596, 159, 177, 'u', 1598, 1613, 159, 177, 'c', 1617, 1631, 159, 177, 't', 1634, 1641, 154, 177, 'i', 1643, 1646, 153, 177, 'd', 1650, 1665, 151, 177, 'o', 1668, 1685, 159, 177, 'r', 1688, 1697, 159, 177, 'C', 1709, 1730, 153, 177, 'S', 1733, 1751, 153, 177, '2', 1764, 1779, 153, 177, '0', 1781, 1797, 153, 177, '0', 1800, 1817, 153, 177, '3', 1820, 1835, 151, 177, '9', 1847, 1863, 151, 177, '3', 1866, 1883, 151, 177, '4', 1883, 1901, 153, 175, '8', 1904, 1919, 151, 177, '4', 1919, 1937, 153, 175, 'S', 1950, 1968, 151, 177, 'A', 1971, 1992, 151, 175, 'I', 1995, 2000, 151, 175, 'N', 2004, 2024, 151, 175, 'T', 2027, 2046, 151, 175, 'O', 2058, 2081, 151, 177, 'U', 2085, 2105, 151, 177, 'E', 2109, 2127, 151, 177, 'N', 2130, 2150, 151, 175, 'C', 2163, 2186, 151, 175, 'e', 2187, 2204, 157, 175, 'd', 2207, 2222, 150, 175, 'e', 2225, 2240, 157, 175, 'x', 2243, 2258, 157, 175], ['T', 1638, 1656, 192, 216, 'Ã‰', 1659, 1677, 186, 217, 'L', 1682, 1697, 193, 217, 'Ã‰', 1701, 1719, 187, 217, 'P', 1722, 1742, 192, 217, 'H', 1746, 1766, 193, 217, 'O', 1770, 1793, 192, 217, 'N', 1796, 1815, 192, 216, 'E', 1820, 1838, 192, 217, '0', 1869, 1886, 190, 216, '1', 1890, 1899, 192, 216, '4', 1914, 1931, 193, 216, '4', 1934, 1950, 193, 216, '0', 1961, 1977, 190, 216, '4', 1980, 1997, 193, 216, '7', 2009, 2024, 192, 216, '0', 2027, 2042, 192, 216, '0', 2055, 2070, 192, 216, '0', 2073, 2090, 192, 216], ['R', 1517, 1538, 232, 258, '.', 1542, 1545, 253, 256, 'C', 1550, 1571, 232, 256, '.', 1575, 1580, 252, 256, 'S', 1584, 1602, 232, 256, '.', 1607, 1611, 252, 256, 'B', 1625, 1643, 232, 256, 'O', 1649, 1670, 231, 258, 'B', 1674, 1692, 232, 256, 'I', 1697, 1701, 232, 256, 'G', 1706, 1728, 232, 256, 'N', 1731, 1751, 232, 256, 'Y', 1754, 1775, 232, 256, 'B', 1788, 1806, 232, 256, '3', 1818, 1835, 231, 256, '3', 1838, 1855, 231, 256, '4', 1855, 1872, 232, 255, '3', 1884, 1899, 232, 256, '6', 1904, 1919, 232, 256, '7', 1922, 1937, 232, 256, '4', 1947, 1964, 232, 256, '9', 1967, 1983, 232, 256, '7', 1986, 2001, 232, 256, '-', 2013, 2022, 244, 249, 'A', 2034, 2055, 231, 255, 'P', 2057, 2075, 231, 255, 'E', 2079, 2097, 231, 256, '4', 2109, 2126, 232, 255, '6', 2129, 2145, 232, 256, '5', 2148, 2163, 232, 256, '2', 2166, 2183, 232, 255, 'Z', 2193, 2211, 231, 255], ['C', 1628, 1647, 271, 297, 'o', 1652, 1670, 279, 297, 'd', 1671, 1689, 273, 297, 'e', 1692, 1709, 279, 298, 'T', 1721, 1739, 273, 297, 'V', 1742, 1763, 273, 297, 'A', 1763, 1787, 273, 297, 'F', 1818, 1835, 273, 297, 'R', 1839, 1859, 273, 297, '8', 1872, 1889, 273, 297, '9', 1890, 1905, 273, 297, '3', 1919, 1932, 273, 297, '3', 1937, 1952, 273, 297, '4', 1953, 1971, 273, 297, '3', 1983, 1998, 273, 297, '6', 2001, 2018, 273, 297, '7', 2021, 2036, 273, 295, '4', 2048, 2064, 274, 297, '9', 2066, 2082, 273, 297, '7', 2085, 2100, 273, 295]]
9   [['h', 1686, 1703, 315, 339, 't', 1706, 1715, 316, 339, 't', 1718, 1727, 316, 339, 'p', 1730, 1748, 321, 345, 'i', 1751, 1757, 321, 339, 'f', 1760, 1769, 315, 339, '/', 1769, 1776, 313, 339, 'w', 1779, 1804, 321, 337, 'w', 1804, 1829, 321, 339, 'w', 1830, 1854, 321, 337, '.', 1859, 1863, 333, 337, 's', 1868, 1883, 319, 339, 'a', 1886, 1901, 321, 337, 'm', 1905, 1929, 321, 337, 's', 1932, 1949, 321, 339, 'u', 1953, 1968, 321, 339, 'n', 1973, 1989, 321, 339, 'g', 1992, 2010, 319, 345, '.', 2015, 2019, 333, 337, 'f', 2021, 2033, 313, 337, 'r', 2034, 2045, 319, 337]]
10  [['N', 1331, 1349, 370, 391, 'C', 1361, 1379, 370, 393, 'O', 1382, 1403, 370, 393, 'M', 1404, 1425, 370, 391, 'P', 1430, 1446, 370, 391, 'T', 1448, 1464, 370, 391, 'E', 1467, 1484, 370, 393, 'C', 1494, 1512, 370, 393, 'L', 1515, 1532, 370, 393, 'I', 1533, 1539, 370, 393, 'E', 1542, 1559, 370, 393, 'N', 1560, 1580, 370, 393, 'T', 1580, 1598, 370, 393]]
```

here is the second csv file:

```
    char    left    right   top bottom
0   'm' 38  104 2456    2492
1   'i' 40  102 2442    2448
2   'i' 40  100 2402    2410
3   'l' 40  102 2372    2382
4   'm' 40  102 2312    2358
5   'u' 40  102 2292    2310
6   'i' 40  104 2210    2260
7   'l' 40  104 2180    2208
8   'i' 40  104 2140    2166
```

EDIT1

```
HERE IS MY output for solution 2 (`input character_position described` )

    1831    1830    level_2 char    left    top right   bottom  FromLine    all_chars_in_same_row
0   0   character_position  0   character_position                  0   character_position
1   1   'm','i','i','l','m','u','i','l','i','l' 0   'm' 38  104 2456    2492    1   'm','i','i','l','m','u','i','l','i','l'
2   1   'm','i','i','l','m','u','i','l','i','l' 1   'i' 40  102 2442    2448    1   'm','i','i','l','m','u','i','l','i','l'
3   1   'm','i','i','l','m','u','i','l','i','l' 2   'i' 40  100 2402    2410    1   'm','i','i','l','m','u','i','l','i','l'
```

l think the probelm comes from the fact that l have in my data :
[[',' , 'A', ',' , '.', ':' , ';', '1'], `[]`, ['m', 'a',]]
so :

```
empty `[ ]`  causes problem for the order. l noticed that when l tried to omit  all [] which are empty beacause l find my csv as follow :
```

in char :  `['a'` rather than `'a'` for values `8794]` rather than `8794` or
`[5345` rather than `5345`
so processed the csv as follow

```
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer='lit_charaters.csv', header=None, usecols=[1,3], names=['character_position','LineIndex'])
    df = df.replace(['\[','\]'], ['',''], regex=True)
cols = ['char','left','right','top','bottom','LineIndex']
df1 = df.positionlrtb.str.strip('[]').str.split(',', expand=True)
df1.columns = [df1.columns % 5, df1.columns // 5]
df1 = df1.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
df1.columns = cols
df1.char = df1.char.replace(['\[','\]'], ['',''], regex=True)
df1['left']=df1['left'].replace(['\[','\]'], ['',''], regex=True)
df1['top']=df1['top'].replace(['\[','\]'], ['',''], regex=True)
df1['right']=df1['right'].replace(['\[','\]'], ['',''], regex=True)
df1['bottom']=df1['bottom'].replace(['\[','\]'], ['',''], regex=True)
df1.to_csv('char.csv')
```

[image]

Then l noticed the following

look at `line 1221 column B` it's empty it replaces `[]` then we get the disorder of columns switched (B and C) due to empty char . `How to solve that ?`
l have also empty line

```
3831    '6' 296 314 3204    3231
3832                    
3833    '1' 480 492 3202    3229
```

Line 3832 should be removed.

in order to get something like this[image]

```
**EDIT2:**
```

In order to solve the problem of `empty rows` and `[]` in list_characters.csv

[['1', 2364, 2382, 1552, 1585], **[]**, ['E', 2369, 2381, 1623, 1640], ['8', 2369, 2382, 1644, 1668]]
and
**[[]]    [[]]**

l did the following :

```
    df1 = df.applymap(lambda x: [y for y in x if len(y) > 0])

    df1 = df1[df1.applymap(len).ne(0).all(axis=1)]

    df1 = df.replace(['\[\],','\[\[\]\]', ''],['','', np.nan], regex=True)

    df1 = df1.dropna()
then

df = pd.read_csv('character_position.csv', index_col=0)

df.positionlrtb = df.positionlrtb.apply(ast.literal_eval)

df.positionlrtb = df.positionlrtb.apply(lambda x: [y for y in x if len(y) > 0])
print (df.head())
      page_number                                       positionlrtb  \
0  1841729699_001  [[m, 38, 104, 2456, 2492, i, 40, 102, 2442, 24...   
1  1841729699_001   [[., 203, 213, 191, 198, 3, 235, 262, 131, 198]]   
2  1841729699_001  [[A, 275, 347, 147, 239, M, 363, 465, 145, 239...   
3  1841729699_001  [[A, 73, 91, 373, 394, D, 93, 112, 373, 396, R...   
4  1841729699_001  [[D, 454, 473, 663, 685, O, 474, 495, 664, 687...   

                    LineIndex  
0      [[mi, il, mu, il, il]]  
1                      [[.3]]  
2                   [[amsun]]  
3  [[adresse, de, livraison]]  
4                [[document]]

cols = ['char','left','top','right','bottom']

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        "a": np.repeat(df.page_number.values, df.positionlrtb.str.len()),
        "b": list(chain.from_iterable(df.positionlrtb))})

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1.b.values.tolist())    
df1.columns = [df1.columns % 5, df1.columns // 5]
df1 = df1.stack().reset_index(drop=True)  
cols = ['char','left','top','right','bottom']
df1.columns = cols
df1[cols[1:]] = df1[cols[1:]].astype(int)   
print (df1)
     char  left   top  right  bottom
0       m    38   104   2456    2492
1       i    40   102   2442    2448
2       i    40   100   2402    2410
3       l    40   102   2372    2382
4       m    40   102   2312    2358
5       u    40   102   2292    2310
6       i    40   104   2210    2260
7       l    40   104   2180    2208
8       i    40   104   2140    2166
```

However :

```
df_data = df_data.character_position.str.strip('[]').str.split(', ', expand=True)
```

returns `None values`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you create required data frame, after stacking , don't remove Index, it holds your line number. Since this is a multilevel indexing , get the first Index- your line number.

```
df_data['LineIndex'] = df_data.index.get_level_values(0)
```

Then you can group by LineIndex column and get all characters for the common LineIndex. This is created as dictionary. Convert this dictionary into data frame and then finally merge this into the actual data

---

> Solution 1

---

```
import pandas as pd

df_data=pd.read_csv('list_characters.csv' , header=None, usecols=[1], names=['character_position'])
df_data = df_data.character_position.str.strip('[]').str.split(', ', expand=True)
df_data.columns = [df_data.columns % 5, df_data.columns // 5]

df_data = df_data.stack() # dont remove Index, it has the line from where this record was created
print  df_data

df_data['FromLine'] = df_data.index.get_level_values(0) #assign line number to a column

cols = ['char','left','top','right','bottom','FromLine']
df_data.columns = cols #assign the new column names

#create a new dictionary
#it contains the line number as key and all the characters from that line as value

DictChar= {k: list(v) for k,v in df_data.groupby("FromLine")["char"]}

#convert dictionary to a dataframe 
df_chars=pd.DataFrame(DictChar.items())
df_chars.columns=cols = ['FromLine','char']

#   Merge dataframes on column 'FromLine'
df_final=df_data.merge(df_chars,on ='FromLine')
cols = ['char','left','top','right','bottom','FromLine','all_chars_in_same_row']
df_final.columns=cols
print df_final
```

---

> Solution 2

---

I personally prefer this solution over the first one. See inline comments for more details

```
import pandas as pd

df_data=pd.read_csv('list_characters.csv', header=None, usecols=[1], names=['character_position'])
df_data = df_data.character_position.str.strip('[]').str.split(', ', expand=True)

x=len(df_data.columns) #get total number of columns 
#get all characters from every 5th column, concatenate and create new column in df_data
df_data[x] = df_data[df_data.columns[::5]].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
# get index of each row. This is the line number for your record
df_data[x+1]=df_data.index.get_level_values(0) 
 # now set line number and character columns as Index of data frame
df_data.set_index([x+1,x],inplace=True,drop=True)

df_data.columns = [df_data.columns % 5, df_data.columns // 5]

df_data = df_data.stack()
df_data['FromLine'] = df_data.index.get_level_values(0) #assign line number to a column
df_data['all_chars_in_same_row'] = df_data.index.get_level_values(1) #assign character values to a column
cols = ['char','left','top','right','bottom','FromLine','all_chars_in_same_row']
df_data.columns=cols
df_data.reset_index(inplace=True) #remove mutiindexing
print df_data[cols]
```

Output

```
      char  left   top right bottom  from line all_chars_in_same_row
0     '.'   203   213   191    198          0  ['.', '3', 'C']
1     '3'  1758  1775   370    391          0  ['.', '3', 'C']
2     'C'   296   305  1492   1516          0  ['.', '3', 'C']
3     'A'   275   347   147    239          1  ['A', 'M', 'D']
4     'M'  2166  2184   370    391          1  ['A', 'M', 'D']
5     'D'   339   362  1815   1840          1  ['A', 'M', 'D']
6     'A'    73    91   373    394          2  ['A', 'D', 'A']
7     'D'  1395  1415   427    454          2  ['A', 'D', 'A']
8     'A'  1440  1455  2047   2073          2  ['A', 'D', 'A']
9     'D'   454   473   663    685          3  ['D', 'O', '0']
10    'O'  1533  1545   487    541          3  ['D', 'O', '0']
11    '0'   339   360  2137   2163          3  ['D', 'O', '0']
12    'A'   108   129   727    751          4  ['A', 'V', 'I']
13    'V'  1659  1677   490    514          4  ['A', 'V', 'I']
14    'I'   339   360  1860   1885          4  ['A', 'V', 'I']
15    'N'    34    51   949    970          5  ['N', '/', '2']
16    '/'  1890  1904   486    505          5  ['N', '/', '2']
17    '2'  1266  1283  1951   1977          5  ['N', '/', '2']
18    'S'  1368  1401    43     85          6  ['S', 'A', '8']
19    'A'  1344  1361   583    607          6  ['S', 'A', '8']
20    '8'  2207  2217  1492   1515          6  ['S', 'A', '8']
21    'S'  1437  1457   112    138          7  ['S', 'o', 'O']
22    'o'  1548  1580   979   1015          7  ['S', 'o', 'O']
23    'O'  1331  1349   370    391          7  ['S', 'o', 'O']
24    'h'  1686  1703   315    339          8  ['h', 't', 't']
25    't'   169   190  1291   1312          8  ['h', 't', 't']
26    't'   169   190  1291   1312          8  ['h', 't', 't']
27    'N'  1331  1349   370    391          9  ['N', 'C', 'C']
28    'C'   296   305  1492   1516          9  ['N', 'C', 'C']
29    'C'   296   305  1492   1516          9  ['N', 'C', 'C']
```

Comment: updated the comments to the code as required, let me know if you are not clear. In you updated code , you are still removing index using reset_index(drop=True). Also you haven't created dictionary to get all the characters from each line

Comment: df_data=pd.read_csv('Check.txt',sep ='  ' ) is not working for me  sep= ',' is needed to work . however l have some ',' comma which are not separators they are chars as m and n ..   l got the following error :

Comment: File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 870, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas/parser.c:10691)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 924, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas/parser.c:11437)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 911, in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas/parser.c:11308)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 2024, in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas/parser.c:27037)
pandas.io.common.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 54 fields in line 4, saw 92

Comment: df_data.columns=['character_position'] ? From where you got this

Comment: l stack with these two lines : df_data.columns=['character_position']  df_data.columns = [df_data.columns % 5, df_data.columns // 5]

Comment: I created a sample file for this and it has ' ' as sep. you can change it according to your needs. 'character_position' is a name that I assigned to the data frame column.

Comment: df_data.columns=['character_position'] is not working for me . l got the following error : Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2802, in set_axis
    (old_len, new_len))
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 3 elements, new values have 1 elements

Comment: l have access to character_position as follow :  df_data.icol(1)

Comment: Can you provide a sample file that is used for this problem ? Since I created one myself its not matching with what you do

Comment: please copy it to stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks, l got error here  df_chars=pd.DataFrame(DictChar.items())     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 345, in __init__
    raise PandasError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')
pandas.core.common.PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: Added another solution , check that. it must faster and comprehensive one

Comment: Please see my results in the following link , l got a strange results(order of letter, numbers, columns ,headers..). l can't share them the file is too long . i tried to share it. but lt exceeds the max characters. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-QJnh0Uw96lM1pORjAxXzFlbUE

Comment: Add one or 2 lines from source file and current output. Also have you updated code here